# Sometimes my "mailto:" function works inside a browser sometimes it doesn't

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, mailto

Sometimes my "mailto:" function works inside a browser (more specifically Google Sheets), sometimes it doesn't. In Google Sheets I have a spreadsheet where, when I click on the cell, it pulls up the following if statement which contains a mailto: instruction so that a form email is created in a mail client, like Outlook:

```
=IF(Q2>0,HYPERLINK("mailto:"&Q2&"?CC=sales@clickitco.com&Subject="&Letter!A$2&"&body="&Letter!$B$2&" "&$AE2&",%0A%0A"&Letter!$C$2&"%0A%0A"&Letter!$D$2&" "&$B2&"%0A%0A"&Letter!$E$2&"%0A%0A "&Letter!$F$2&"%0A%0A "&Letter!$G$2&"%0A%0A "&Letter!$H$2&"%0A%0A "&Letter!$I$2&"%0A%0A "&Letter!$J$2& "%0A%0ASincerely,","email"),"")
```

The cells it refers to are paragraphs of the email.

Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. I have looked at the browser's pop-up blockers, the restrictions on any Java, etc. Nothing seems to prevent this from creating an email. I have tried it in Chrome and Explorer, the current versions of each. I have tired it on several versions of Windows, from 7 to 10. Same results.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try it on a simple web page first. Perhaps, the google sheet cell has prevent the link default action, or the google sheet has prevent some client event bound to cell. You can also try other event bind method, such as modify the html source in debug mode, add the "mailto:" to a link directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but yes, I can get it to work as I said. I mean, if I change what is contained in the cells, like shorten it, the mailto: works and pops up my mail client - in my case, Outlook. But what is this you're saying about Chrome preventing the event? How can I force this?

Comment: I think I have it working somehow. There seems to have been injected some odd characters, and the code is sensitive to the length of the text in each cell it is calling.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. Sometimes, we bind event handler to the parent element of we expected element. But if another event handler is bound to the expected element directly, and the event bubble is cancelled, your handler bound to  parent element will not be executed.
I only speculate on the possibility. But it seems does not fit your case.